# evernote api search + nodejs: get search results in two notebooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

it seems Evernote's search grammar doesn't allow multiple notebooks, but I still want to obtain all notes containing 'somesearch' in "notebook 1" or in "notebook 2".

I can obtain one search in one notebook:

```
var token = 'xxxxXXX';

const Evernote = require('evernote');

const nFilter = new Evernote.NoteStore.NoteFilter({
  words: 'somesearch notebook:"notebook 1"',
  ascending: false
});

const rSpec = {};
rSpec.includeTitle = true;

var client = new Evernote.Client({token: token, sandbox: false});
var noteStore = client.getNoteStore();

noteStore.findNotesMetadata(nFilter, 0, 50, rSpec).then(function(notesMetadataList) {
    console.log("Found " + notesMetadataList.notes.length + " notes.");
    console.log();
    console.log("Here are their titles: ");

    var titles = [];
    for (var i =0;i<notesMetadataList.notes.length;i++) {
      titles[i]=notesMetadataList.notes[i].title;
      console.log(titles[i]);
    }
  }).catch(function(err){
      console.log('Error:',err);
  });
```

But i can't figure out how to make a second search on "notebook 2", and append their titles to variable `titles`... BTW, i'm very new on node.js programming...

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: untested

Short answer is you need to iterate over your notebooks and then sum up the results before reporting.  I edited your code leaving some pointer comments.

```
// always put your imports first
const Evernote = require('evernote');

// default to const
const token = 'xxxxXXX';

const client = new Evernote.Client({token: token, sandbox: false});
const noteStore = client.getNoteStore();

// async await makes things cleaner
async function showTitles (noteBooks) {
  const queries = [];
  const rSpec = { includeTitle: true };
  // the of form of the for loop avoids i++
  for (const noteBook of noteBooks) {
    const nFilter = new Evernote.NoteStore.NoteFilter({
      words: `somesearch notebook:"${noteBook}"`,
      ascending: false
    });
    queries.push(noteStore.findNotesMetadata(nFilter, 0, 50, rSpec))
  }
  // run in parallel
  const results = await Promise.all(queries);
  let found = 0;
  let titles = [];
  for (const result of results) {
    found += result.notes.length;
    titles = titles.concat(results.notes.map(n => n.title));
  }
  console.log(`Found ${found} notes.

Here are their titles:
${titles.join('\n')}`);
}

showTitles(['notebook 1', 'notebook 2']).catch(function(err){
  console.log('Error:',err);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I copy-pasted on ever.js and when running `node ever.js` i got this error `Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at showTitles (ever.js:27:42)
    at <anonymous>                                   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)`

Comment: That's a typo on my part, it should be `titles = titles.concat(result.notes.map(n => n.title));` which is the current result, not the array of results